# Auto run Javascript on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a piece of JavaScript automatically when a page loads.
The code itself simply pops up a link to our self service portal...

```
// Requires jQuery!
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "selfserviceportal.com",
    type: "get",
    cache: true,
    dataType: "script"
});
```

I've attempted using onload and onclick with no success.
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: how did you try to use onload??

Comment: I removed the [tag:java] tag. You should know that Java and JavaScript are two **entirely** different things!

Comment: add an 'success' handler to get a feedback when the request finishes

Comment: What is happening in your case? is the ajax request going? what is the response of the request?

Answer (score 2):

[jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) Specifies a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: the name of the link is wrong, it should be called `JQuery.ready()`

Answer (score 1):

Just include your JS file at the end of the document and execute your code.

Read more on my relevant blog post [You Don't Need the DOM Ready event](http://thanpol.as/javascript/you-dont-need-dom-ready/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
  console.log('Page loaded!');
});
```